# Azure App Service - Multi-container app with Auto-Heal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

The article ["Announcing Auto Heal for Linux"](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/04/21/Announcing-Autoheal-for-Azure-App-Service-Linux.html) said It can work in Linux now.

But I found that it does not work in our App service.

[image]

And then, I create an easy Auto-Heal. Nothing happens.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem is: The [docker-compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-multi-container) is in Preview Level.

Azure App Service does not support it for Auto-Heal